# Cannot connect with SSMS to SQL Server on Docker using Server Name

Tags: sql-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, serverless, remote-server, docker-machine

I created a SQL server service(2019) using a Docker service. Now the issue is I am able to connect my Docker SQL instance using localhost(localhost,1433) id. But, when I tried to connect using server(DemoSQL2) it's giving an network instance specific error.

```
------------------------------
Cannot connect to DemoSQL2,1433.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - TCP Provider: ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver--1-database-engine-error
```

I am looking for an solution for this to be happen or the appropriate guidelines

Docker
MSSQL server
Serverless
Remote connectivity
WSL

Comment: Why not just use `localhost`..? Why do you want to use (presumably) the name of the host to connect to the localhost?

Comment: Presumably when you're connecting to localhost,1433 you're doing that from the Docker host. From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, so localhost resolves to themselves. Are the two containers in the same Docker composition, or at least in the same Docker network so that they can resolve each other's container names? If not you might need to try using the special Docker host name: host.docker.internal,1433. (Note: this only works in Docker for Desktop.)